# Where is bootstrap.js' 'scroll.scroll-spy.data-api' event triggered?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate bootstrap.js and backbone.js. Unfortunately, their shared use of the '#' resource renders some of bootstrap's functionality useless. As such, I need to replicate bootstrap.js' data-spy plugin. The plugin listens for the 'scroll.scroll-spy.data-api' event and runs some code every time it is triggered.

```
34 this.$scrollElement = $element.on('scroll.scroll-spy.data-api', process)
```

I cannot seem to find where this event is triggered, even after searching the entire bootstrap codebase. Is this an event specific to bootstrap, and if so, where is it defined?

Here is a link to the entire file: 
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for `$element` is determined by [line 31](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js#L31).  If the ScrollSpy plugin is to attached to the `<body>`, then the `window` is used as the emitter of **scroll** events.  Otherwise, the element it is attached to is used.

The string `'scroll.scroll-spy.data-api'` is a namespaced version of the [standard **scroll** event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/scroll).  See the [jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) for more info on namespacing events.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize how javascript namespaces events.